# Using traits for mixing core libraries in Scala

Tags: scala, oop, traits

I'm working on multi SBT project in Scala. I extracted core things into separate SBT project. This includes handling config, third party libraries (init RMQ client, init Redis client etc) and some models.

So I organised some things like loading config in trait and I then mix this trait where I need it and just use `config` method defined in `Configuration` trait, which loads config for specific environment (based on environment variable). I did same for database, so I load PostgreSQL, open connection and then mix that trait where I need it and just use `database` method which I can use for executing queries and other.

Is this good approach in you opinion? Advantage is that I do not have to handle database connection and initialisations in each project and also code is much shorter. However, there is one issue with closing connection. Where to close connection in trait where Database is mixed?

Any help on the topic is appreciated. Thanks

Amer

Answer (score 1):

Regarding connections, you should be closing them (returning to pool) whenever you are done with them, that is orthogonal to mix-in implementation.

As for configuration and such, I like this approach, but the problem with it is that most of the time you want things like loaded `config` to be singletons, but if you simply do something like

```
  trait Configuration { 
     val config = loadConfig
  }

  class Foo with Configuration
  class Bar with Configuration
  val f1 = new Foo
  val f2 = new Foo
  val b1 = new Bar
  val b2 = new Bar
```

then, you'll end up loading four different copies of the config. 
One way around this is to delegate `loadConfig` to a singleton object:

```
 object Configuration {
    val config = loadConfig
 }
 trait Configuration { 
    def config = Configration.config
 }
```

This works, but makes it much harder to unit-test and override the functionality (what if I want my config loaded from a database sometimes?)

Another possibility is a proxy class:

```
trait Configuration {
  def loadConfig: Config
  lazy val config: Config = loadConfig
}

class ConfigurationProxy(cfg: Configuration) extends Configuration {
   def loadConfig = cfg.config
}

object Main extends App with Configuration {
   def loadConfig = ??? // executed only one per application 
   ...
}

class Foo extends ConfigurationProxy(Main)
class Bar extends ConfigurationProxy(Main)

val f1 = new Foo
val f2 = new Foo
val b1 = new Bar
val b2 = new Bar
```

Now, all four variables are looking at the same `Config` instance. 
But if you have a function somewhere that wants a `Configuration`, you can still pass any of these in:

```
def connectToDB(cfg: Configuration) = ???

connectToDB(Main)
connectToDB(f1)
connectToDB(b2)
```

etc.